# SQL Server: Find most popular category of products bought per user for use in subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have three tables: `categories` (id, name), `products` (id, category_id, name)), and `purchases` (id, user_id, product_id). A `product` belongs to a `category`. Users can purchase many `products`. My intention is to find the most popular `category` per user.

However, I need to use the result-set of the query as a sub-query, so using any `ORDER BY` statements unfortunately is off, due to SQL Server limitations (the dreaded `The ORDER BY clause is invalid in views, inline functions, derived tables, and subqueries, unless TOP is also specified.` error).

My approach has been to create a list of all `purchases` per user per `category`. I then have a `MAX` function to pick out the maximum amount of `purchases`. I JOIN that result to the original query (duplicated as a sub-query) to retrieve the `category_id` in question, and finally I grab the category name.

There are two issues with my query:

1. Obviously I'd prefer not using the same query twice in my code. However, I cannot rely on using CTEs or temp tables, as the result of this query is intended to be linked to a view that has a subset of user-data as it is, and the VIEW code is intended to be used in a third-party package, that can handle only basic SQL code.
2. In case of a tie (say a useer bought 4 `products`, 2 from 2 `categories` each), I end up with a duplicate row for that user.

Fiddle:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8821b/5

I'd appreciate it if anyone be able to help me figure out a way to ensure only a single row is returned per user, as well as a way to remove the duplicate sub-query.

Thanks!

Comment: with case 2 where there is a tie and 2 records, which record should you choose? first?

Comment: @Tanner Sure, the first returned result would work for me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, thanks for providing the example in SQLFiddle.  It makes helping ALOT easier.

You can use row_number for a more precise way of getting the "top" record.  In this example I chose to use category_name as a secondary sort criterion after the count.

```
SELECT user_id, category_name, category_count
FROM
(
  SELECT 
      user_id, COUNT(1) as category_count, category_name, 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
          PARTITION BY user_id 
          ORDER BY COUNT(1) DESC, category_name ASC) 
          as ordinal_position
  FROM
      purchases p 
          JOIN products p2 ON p.product_id = p2.id
          JOIN categories c ON p2.category_id = c.id        
  GROUP BY user_id, category_name
 ) a
WHERE ordinal_position = 1
ORDER BY category_count DESC
```

[Example at SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8821b/27/0)

Comment: I came to the same solution.

Comment: +1 A window function within a group by, didn't know that was okay.  Well done!

Comment: That's awesome. I'm pretty proficient at SQL, but the whole analytic function-set is still a bit of uncharted territory to me. I've used them for specific examples, but didn't know the above was possible. Thanks a bunch! As for the Fiddle, I provided it exactly because it makes it easier to see what's going on :) I spend enough time on SO to realize anything that helps us save time when answering guarantees a faster response.